# Javascript ignore NaN characters in string

Tags: javascript, regex, string, escaping

Bear with me because I'm very new to javascript.

I'm making a simple progress bar script. I'm having the user input the progress percentage into one of the variables.

Instead of giving an error and having the user re-input their number, what can I do to make it so that javascript will ignore any characters that are not numbers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can remove all non-digit symbols with regex:

```
user_input = user_input.replace(/[^0-9]/g, "");
```

Example:

```
> "a347adsf73".replace(/[^0-9]/g, "");
"34773"
```

Comment: Will this also replace characters? For example if someone were to put in 30%, I would need it to take out the % symbol.

Comment: This will only leave digits in the `user_input`.